# why get "Cannot read from a closed TextReader"

Tags: .net, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sqlclr

i have a SQL CLR function that return the Json from a Web Api, here es my code

```
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction]
public static SqlString Funcion()
{
    SqlString document;
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("URL");
    request.Method = "GET";
    request.ContentLength = 0;
    request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream);
    document = (SqlString)readStream.ReadToEnd();
    return document;
}
```

i delete the next code because i think that it was the problem

```
     //response.Close();
    //readStream.Close();
```

but i still gettin the error

```
System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot read from a closed TextReader System.ObjectDisposedException: 
at System.IO.__Error.ReaderClosed()
at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadToEnd()
at UserDefinedFunctions.Funcion()
```

i inspect the dll withILSpy and my code looks different
[image] 
someone can helpme please. i tried this code in an application cosole to write the result in a file and works perfectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to say exactly as you have separated the current code from the commented-out / removed code. But the general concept of using `ReadToEnd` into a string to return the string is the correct approach.

One thing you absolutely need to do if you don't want this code to trash your SQL Server is to properly dispose of all disposable objects. You should be using `using()` constructs as they will include the proper `try...finally` structure to ensure that all resources are properly disposed no matter where in the nested set of them an exception occurs.

Now, the code shown in the image taken from ILspy shows the immediate problem in that it is returning `readStream.ReadToEnd()`. Once you put your code into the proper `using` constructs, and do the `document = (SqlString)readStream.ReadToEnd()` in the middle, then this will work as expected.

```cs
string document;
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("URL");
request.Method = "GET";
request.ContentLength = 0;
request.UseDefaultCredentials = true; // don't use CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
  using (Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream())
  {
    using (StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream))
    {
      document = readStream.ReadToEnd();
    }
  }
}

return new SqlString(document);
```

---

**UPDATE**

- With the code above, O.P. still gets `Cannot read from a closed TextReader` error.
- O.P. mentioned that the web service returns a response of approximately 8 MB.
- With the code above, I downloaded an 11.6 MB file without a problem.
- With the code above, O.P. was able to successfully retrieve a response from 
  https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/ without a problem.
- The problem is *not* the mapping of the return datatype since mapping it to `NVARCHAR(4000)` instead of `NVARCHAR(MAX)` would result in the following error:

  > Msg 6522, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
  >   A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "xxxxxx":
  >   System.Data.SqlServer.TruncationException: Trying to convert return value or output parameter of size 24233896 bytes to a T-SQL type with a smaller size limit of 8000 bytes.
  >   System.Data.SqlServer.TruncationException:
  >         at System.Data.SqlServer.Internal.CXVariantBase.StringToWSTR(String pstrValue, Int64 cbMaxLength, Int32 iOffset, EPadding ePad)

Comment: thanks for you help! but still getting the same error :(,

Comment: i tried this code in a console application to write the json in a file and works perfectly

Comment: It might be something with the page you are calling. I pasted the code in my answer into a new DB Project in VS 2015, changed "URL" to be a `SqlString` input param, and it works just fine.

Comment: yes, its something wrong with the web service, i tried with https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/ and works well, i will check the web because its a 8 million of characters the result. Thanks for your help

Comment: @VictorHernandez Why didn't you mention that the response was expected to be 8 MB? That is certainly a relevant detail that might affect this. It could be that a default timeout or max size of something is different in SQL Server's CLR host (though with using SQL Server 2012 that is less likely). Was the Console App that worked running on the same server as SQL Server itself (not necessarily the same machine running SSMS)? I will test with an 8 MB file and report back.

Comment: @VictorHernandez Well, I just tested on a file that is 12.1 million characters (11.6 MB) and it was again just fine. I have updated my answer with this info, and that your external test succeeded. Is this web service on an internal network? If yes, is there any authentication needed? The web service call from SQLCLR, based on this code, will be coming from the service account running the MSSQLSERVER service, and _not_ from you, which is different than running it from a Console App in which the web service call would be coming from you.